# Is there an "is a type of" functionality in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to catch occurrences of general classes of objects using NLTK. For example, `trout` and `herring` are *types of* `fish`, `eagles` and `sparrows` are *types of* `birds`. Is there any functionality in NLTK (or any other library for that matter) to help me do this?

I am not looking for synonyms since they are just another way of saying the same thing... so for example using `wordnet.synsets` I get the following as synonyms for 'sparrow':

`'hedge_sparrow', 'dunnock', 'Prunella_modularis', 'sparrow', 'true_sparrow'`.

And for synonyms of 'bird' I get:

`'doll', 'snort', 'skirt', 'birdwatch', 'chick', 'hiss', 'hoot', 'raspberry', 'bird', 'Bronx_cheer', 'boo', 'shuttlecock', 'razzing', 'birdie', 'shuttle', 'wench', 'fowl', 'dame', 'razz'`.

I am looking for a way to say that `sparrow` is a type of `bird`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admire your ingenuity in trying to exploit the wordnet similarity score, but I doubt it's going to be enough for your purposes. What you are after is the *hypernym* relation, and Wordnet synsets conveniently provide it via the `hypernyms()` method. (Lemmas also have a `hypernyms()` method, for some reason; but it is always empty; don't let it confuse you.)

Here's what Wordnet can tell you about the word "sparrow":

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets("sparrow")
[Synset('sparrow.n.01'), Synset('hedge_sparrow.n.01')]
>>> sparrow = wn.synsets("sparrow")[0]
>>> sparrow.hypernyms()
[Synset('passerine.n.01')]
>>> sparrow.hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()
[Synset('bird.n.01')]
>>> sparrow.hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()
[Synset('vertebrate.n.01')]
```

As you see, Wordnet takes you from *sparrow* to *bird* in two steps, not one. That's just what Wordnet happens to contain.

More generally, what you are looking for is a *taxonomy* of everything in your corpus, that is, a hierarchical vocabulary of every interesting concept in your domain. Note that I keep qualifying, as in "your corpus", "your domain". There are many different ways to classify things by "type". Wheat is a plant, but you could also say that it's a cereal grain (a sub-type of plant), or that it is a seed, a foodstuff, an ingredient in food products, etc. (Never mind that "wheat" is also a color, etc.)

So the ideal solution for your needs is a taxonomy *of things that you are interested in,* and that is *suitable for your purposes.* If you are dealing with a specific domain, there might well be one; try googling or asking in a suitable stack exchange. But many such resources are in the RDF format, and require different tools and techniques than you may be used to. One massive, free resource is [dbpedia](https://wiki.dbpedia.org/), extracted from wikipedia. Here's the entry on [swallow](http://dbpedia.org/page/Swallow) to give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you @alexis, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I found a crude workaround that I can use in the meantime, but I would still appreciate any help if a better way exists.

It turns out there's a synonym `path_similarity()` function that gives the similarity between two wordnet synonyms. I wrote a function to find the similarity between all the combinations of synonyms for two items and took the highest similarity value. I will have to set a similarity threshold above which I can consider one thing a *type of* another thing.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

def getSimilarity(thing1, thing2):
    similarity = []
    for syn1 in wordnet.synsets(thing1):
        for syn2 in wordnet.synsets(thing2):
            sim = syn1.path_similarity(syn2)
            if sim:
                similarity.append(sim)
    return max(similarity)

print('fish<->fish similarity: {}'.format(getSimilarity('fish', 'fish')))
print('fish<->trout similarity: {}'.format(getSimilarity('fish', 'trout')))
print('fish<->herring similarity: {}'.format(getSimilarity('fish', 'herring')))
print('fish<->cat similarity: {}'.format(getSimilarity('fish', 'cat')))
print('fish<->dog similarity: {}'.format(getSimilarity('fish', 'dog')))
print('..........')
print('bird<->bird similarity: {}'.format(getSimilarity('bird', 'bird')))
print('bird<->sparrow similarity: {}'.format(getSimilarity('bird', 'sparrow')))
print('bird<->eagle similarity: {}'.format(getSimilarity('bird', 'eagle')))
print('bird<->cat similarity: {}'.format(getSimilarity('bird', 'cat')))
print('bird<->fish similarity: {}'.format(getSimilarity('bird', 'fish')))
```

Output:

```
fish<->fish similarity: 1.0
fish<->trout similarity: 0.5
fish<->herring similarity: 0.3333333333333333
fish<->cat similarity: 0.2
fish<->dog similarity: 0.2
..........
bird<->bird similarity: 1.0
bird<->sparrow similarity: 0.3333333333333333
bird<->eagle similarity: 0.3333333333333333
bird<->cat similarity: 0.25
bird<->dog similarity: 0.25
..........
bird<->fish similarity: 0.25
```

Comment: Hyper-/Hyponyms =)

Comment: Thanks @alvas, I didn't know that's what they were called!